# how to use django-background-tasks

Tags: python, django, background-task

I am making a django application. To calculate the rank of the feeds based on lines and comment, I am trying to use django-background-tasks. the function I am using in nodes models is:

```
    @background(schedule=60)
    def get_score(self):
        p = self.likes+self.comments    # popularity
        t = (now()-self.date).total_seconds()/3600  # age_in_hrs
        # last_activity =
        n = self.admin_score
        score = (p/pow((t+1), 1.2))*n
        self.score = score
        return score
```

But I am not seeing any change in score. That means that I am doing it in a right way and i am missing the basic concept. Can somebody tell me how to use django-background-tasks to schedule task or refer me to some existing documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be using it the wrong way.

Let's say you have to execute some particular task say, send a mail 5 minutes after a user signs up. So what do you do is:

Create a task using django-background-task.

```
@background(schedule=60*5)
def send_html_mail_post(id, template):
    u = User.objects.get(id=id)
    user_email = u.email
    subject = "anything"
    html_content = template.format(arguments)
    from_email, to = from_email, user_email
    text_content = ''
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
```

The decorator at the top defines after how much time of the function getting called upon is the actual event gonna happen.

Call it when you need it.

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        up = UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
        up.save()
        tasks.send_welcome_email(up.user.id, template=template)
```

This creates the task and saves it in database and also storing in db the time when it will be executed.

The kind of thing you want to do, doing something at regular intervals, that can more easily be done by creating cron job.

What you do is, you create a function as you have shown in the question. And then define a cron job to call it every 5 minutes or whatever interval you want.

Answer (score 25):

Since the question seems to be quite generic, I believe this is the right place for a quick cheat sheet about "how to use django-background-tasks" based on my personal experience. Hopefully I won't be the only one to use it :)

### Environment

- Python 3.8
- Django 3.1

### Installation

I like [pipenv](https://docs.pipenv.org/) so:

```
> cd [my-django-project root directory]
> pipenv install django-background-tasks
```

Now add 'background_task' to INSTALLED_APPS in *settings.py*:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'background_task',
    # ...
)
```

and perform database migrations to ensure the django-background-tasks schema is in place:

```
> pipenv shell
(my-django-project) bash-3.2$  python manage.py migrate
```

### Creating and registering a Task

Any Python function can be a task, we simply need to apply the *@background* annotation to register it as such:

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=10)
def do_something(s1: str, s1: str) -> None:
   """
   Does something that takes a long time
   :param p1: first parameter
   :param p2: second parameter
   :return: None
   """
   pass
```

Now we can call the function as usual in our project:

```
do_something("first parameter", "second parameter")
```

It is important to note that calling the function does **not** actually execute its code; rather a Task record is stored into the database by the "django-background-tasks" module, more precisely into the "background_task" table. For this reason, writing a task function that returns something is of little use, because the task is going to be executed in background at a later moment anyway, so the "value" returned by the function at the time it is invoked is almost meaningless. The only use case I see for a return value is for testing purposes, see the *Testing a Task* section below.

### Processing Tasks

In order to actually run a registered task we have to employ the following management command:

```
> python manage.py process_tasks
```

Please refer to the [module's documentation](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for a description of the command options.
As other users have already pointed out, it is usual to wrap this command in a cron job to make sure tasks are periodically processed. In this case, the *duration* option might turn out to be useful: it represents the number of seconds the process_task command is kept running. By default the duration is 0, which means "run it forever" but this is quite risky in my view, because if for some reason the command crashes or is interrupted, your tasks won't be processed anymore and a long time might pass before you realize it.

A better way is to set the duration to a well defined time, for example 15 minutes, and then configure a cron job to run every 15 minutes to restart the processing command. This way if the command crashes it will get restarted by the cron job later anyway.

### Testing a Task

Testing a task via the "process_tasks" administrative command is awful, we should stick to Python [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#module-unittest) module for that, which is also the "Django way".

I am not going to discuss about *unittest* in this post of course, I only want to point out that during a unit test you want to execute the function in a synchronous way, just like a normal Python function. The syntax for that is as follow:

```
do_something.now("first parameter", "second parameter")
```

The modifier "now" runs the function and wait for it to terminate. This is the only use case when a return value is useful in my view. With a return value at hand you can use the full power of the "assert*" functions provided by *unittest*.

### Checking if a Task is already running

Sometimes it may happen that you don't want the same task to be run multiple times. For example I frequently use background tasks for training Machine Learning models, which takes a lot of time. To prevent my data to be messed up, I prefer to make sure that another training task on the same model cannot be started before the previous one is complete.

For this to work, I have to check if the task is already running before starting a new one; but how to uniquely identify a task? For me the simple way is to assign a "verbose_name" to the task, which can be done at the time the task is scheduled:

```
do_something("first parameter", "second parameter", verbose_name="my_task_verbose_name")
```

Now, if I want to check whether this task is already running or not, I can simply read the *background_task* table and verify there is no task with the same "verbose name" therein. This can very easily be done by leveraging the *Task* model provided by "django-background-tasks" itself:

```
from background_task.models import Task

tasks = Task.objects.filter(verbose_name="my_task_verbose_name")
if len(tasks) == 0:
    # no task running with this name, go ahead!
    pass
else:
    # task already running
    pass
```

Needless to say, we have to make sure the verbose names assigned to our tasks are unique.

### Further Readings

[Django Background Tasks documentation](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: thanks. "Checking if a Task is already running" is missing from the official documentation

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler I know but I needed that function and since I had to browse into the package code to figure it out, I felt like sharing this. Glad it was helpful.

Comment: in your example on "Checking if a task is already running" @SalBorrelli, if that filter was running from within a scheduled task function, would the function have a way to access its own verbose name — outside of having to running a separate filter to find itself?

Comment: @txbarnesx I don't know the details of your specific use case of course, but if you need access to the verbose_name of a scheduled task from within the function then nothing prevents you from passing it as an additional parameter I guess, like in `def do_something(s1: str, s1: str, name: str) -> None:` and then `do_something("first parameter", "second parameter", "my_task_verbose_name", verbose_name="my_task_verbose_name")`. I am pretty sure there must be a better way, maybe via kwargs or kind of, but the solution above should do. Let me know if you find a better way.

Comment: Mm nice yeah I was thinking the same re: kwargs, @SalBorrelli. I'll look into it, but the added param is an easy fallback

Comment: How can I run process_tasks in production? I wrote a .service file to run "python manage.py process_tasks"

Comment: @TanvirAhmed if your production server is a Linux box I believe the easiest way to go is to configure a cron job for it. For example, add this line to the crontab to run `process_tasks` every 30 minutes: `*/30 * * * * . /path/to/your/.service`

Answer (score 8):

There is a difference between django-background-task and django-background-task**s**.
django-background-task was unmaintained and incompatible with newer Django versions. We updated and extended it with new features a while ago and maintaining the new backward compatible package django-background-task**s** on [Github](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks). The new django-background-tasks app can be downloaded or installed from the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-background-tasks).

Comment: Hey, I am using Django-background-tasks for my project. There is a problem where it is repeating the tasks multiple times. Do you know why that might happen?
I am running my django server with 4 workers. can that affect it?

Answer (score 3):

You should run `python manage.py process_tasks` as described [here](https://github.com/lilspikey/django-background-task#running-tasks). You can add it to crontab to execute periodically.

UPD:

1. You don't need to run `process_tasks` using crontab cause this command internally sleeps every 5 seconds (this value is configurable) and then again checks whether there is any task to run.
2. Your task looks strange. You should declare it as global function in separate file and pass `id` of model inside it, fetch object by `id` do calculations and save your object.

Comment: Ok, that means I can't schedule tasks in models or views itself

Comment: @Rohit I think you can leave this method inside `models.py` (separate file is just advice from documentation) but as global function with `id` as parameter cause task parameters are stored in json format in db so you cannot pass your object cause it cannot be reproduced from json later.

Comment: when i run python manage.py process_tasks, i get this error :

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\background_task\models.py:28: RemovedInDjango18War
ning: `Manager.get_query_set` method should be renamed 
`get_queryset`.
  class TaskManager(models.Manager):

Unknown command: 'process_tasks' 
what am i missing here

Comment: @Rohit to expose its commnads you should add `'background_task'` to `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: yeah.. done that.. ran migrations, python manage.py process_tasks working fine.. in tasks.py i have this:

@background(schedule=5)
def create_node():
    user = User.objects.get(id=4)
    Node.objects.create(post='it's a time based node', user=user, category='F') 
how do i add a task to background task table in the database?

Comment: @Rohit as I understand you should actually run it somewhere in your code. Just write `create_node()` and new `Task` will be created and run in 5 seconds.

Comment: yeah, it's working fine, can i do something to get the tasks automated on my linux server independent of any view

Comment: @Rohit you mean to run concrete task periodically?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80455/discussion-between-rohit-and-bellum).