# Django Background-tasks interval

Tags: django, background

I am using background_task lib in django app
I am trying to execute simple function every interval (5 min) 
How can I set the interval

Code in views.py

```
@background(schedule=60)
def hello(repeat=60*5):
    print("Hello")
```

and I run in powershell

```
python manage.py process_tasks
```

but it not execute every 5 min I think it execute every second
how can I set it??

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/573618/1531971 Probable duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30816134/1531971

Comment: I don't get idea, background-tasks not enough to create periodic task ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to repeat a task every 5 mins you have to pass the repeat argument when you call it not when you deff it

```
def hello():
    print("Hello")

hello(repeat=300)
```

here are the docs where you can read more about it
https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#repeating-tasks