# Does django_background_tasks support django 3 and python 3.7?

Tags: python, django, django-views

app/tasks.py

```
from background_task import background

@background(schedule=60)
def schedule_task():
    print('running_tasks')
```

app/views.py

```
schedule_task(repeat=300, repeat_until=obj.end_date)
```

I have placed `django_background_tasks` into the INSTALLED_APPS and run migrate.

But When I try to run the tasks with the command `python manage.py process_tasks` the command doesn't work at all. When I hit the enter after writing the command nothing happens.

Comment: @user1242848 have you solved the problem? Do update on your status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, make sure that you are using django-background-task**s** and not django-background-task.

As @phi mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816134/how-to-use-django-background-tasks)

> There is a difference between django-background-task and django-background-task**s**.
> django-background-task was unmaintained and incompatible with newer Django versions. We updated and extended it with new features a while ago and maintaining the new backward compatible package django-background-task**s** on [Github](https://github.com/arteria/django-background-tasks). The new django-background-tasks app can be downloaded or installed from the [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-background-tasks).

Running `python manage.py process_tasks` is not alone to get this working. You need to first have the server active and running and then in another `terminal/cmd-line` run the above command.

See [here](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from the docs.

Comment: not working nothing happens after entering the command

Comment: Is your server up and running? And you try the cmd in another terminal?

Comment: This time it worked. But I got on question. Does it take the django settings timezone ?And the difference between `schedule` and `repeat`

Comment: I would think so, though i am not entirely sure. I will look into and update later on.