# Django : Run task in background immediately

Tags: python, django, background-task

Similarly to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30816134/how-to-use-django-background-tasks), I don't understand how the django-background-tasks module works. What I want is to have a button which would start a task in background so it doesn't block the front. The task has to be run as soon as the click occurs.

Reading the [docs](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#creating-and-registering-tasks) I thought that I only had to define my task as a function preceded by the decorator `@background(schedule=1)` then calling the function would start the task one second after the click handler was run.

> Calling notify_user as normal will schedule the original function to be run 60 seconds from now:

However this is not what happens. What happens is that a new task is created after each click (I could understand that by requesting the background_task database thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64666683/14606814)) but none ever runs.

The command `python manage.py process_tasks` seems to run one task defined previously before stopping. If no task has been defined, then it waits for a task to be defined for up to  `duration` seconds (specified when running the command). This behavior is not what I expected while reading the [documentation](https://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#running-tasks).

> duration - Run task for this many seconds (0 or less to run forever) - default is 0

I don't think creating a crontab that calls `python manage.py process_tasks` every second is relevant, does this mean I have to manually call the command myself so it runs when I want ? Isn't the command supposed to always be running so it handles all tasks when they are scheduled to be run ?

The fact that the command only runs one task per run is troubling to me, what if I defined 1000 small tasks to be run in background in a minute, would the command ever catch up ?

Comment: Do you have to use django-background-tasks?

Comment: I initialy tried to just spawn a process for each task, but I ran into an issue when trying to force stop some tasks (using signals), because I ended up with some zombie processes. django-background-tasks seemed to be a module that could enable me to do what I wanted.

Comment: I don't have to use this module, as a matter of fact, if someone knows a better way to do what I want, please feel free to share, I would much appreciate it.

Comment: okay then use celery. https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ this is a tutorial that you can check. Celery is much much better and tasks start to run immediately as you wish.